# How to get Child product according to option selected from Configurable product Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart

I have this code in my addtocart :

```
 <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
        ?>
        <ul id="list-nbr-possible">
            <?php foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { ?>
                <li class="myli" id="div<?php echo $child->getId()?>" style="display:none;list-style:none;color:green">
                    <?php
                    $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($child->getId());
                    $pièces=$child->getCustomAttributes("nbre_pieces_par_caisse");
                    $productData= $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($child->getId());
                    $nb_pc= $productData->getData('nbre_pieces_par_caisse');
                    $msg  = "Nombre de pièces totales: <pan class='qty_selected'>1</pan> X <pan class='nbre_pieces'>$nb_pc</pan> égale à <pan class='nbre_pieces_tot'>$nb_pc</pan>";
                    echo $msg;

                    ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
    } else {
        $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
        echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
    }
    ?>

    <p id="nbr-pieces-tot" style="color:green;display:none;"></p>
    <input id="nbre_pieces_par_caisse"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $nb_pc; ?>"/>
```

and this is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
            selpro();
        });
    });
    function selpro () {
        var selected_options = {};
        jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
            var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('attribute-id');
            var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('option-selected');
            //console.log(attribute_id, option_selected);
            if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
            selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
        });

        var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
        var found_ids = [];
        //console.log(product_id_index);
        jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
            //console.log(product_id);
            var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
                return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
            }
            if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
                found_ids.push(product_id);
            }
        });

        console.log(found_ids);

        if (found_ids.length) {
            var selected_product_id = found_ids[0];
            jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
            var qty_selected = jQuery("input#qty").val();
            var nbre_pieces = jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id+' .nbre_pieces').text();
            nbre_pieces = parseInt(nbre_pieces, 10);
            qty_selected = parseInt(qty_selected, 10);
            var nb_piece_tot = qty_selected * nbre_pieces;
            jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id+' .qty_selected').text(qty_selected);
            jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id+' .nbre_pieces_tot').text(nb_piece_tot);
            jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id).toggle();
        }
    }
});
```

i want to have all the attributes of options dropbox but here i find that if one is not aswatch the script does not work any help please

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?